# Let $f(x)= \frac {1}{\sqrt{|[|x|-1]|-5}}$ where $[ .]$ is greatest integer function, Find domain of $f(x)$ ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> **Problem**: Let 
>   $$f(x)= \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{|\bigl[|x|-1\bigr]|-5}}$$
>   where $\bigl[.\bigr]$  is greatest integer function. Find  domain of $f(x)$.

**Solution**: The function $f$ is defined for $|\bigl[|x|-1\bigr]|-5>0$. So 
$$|\bigl[|x|-1\bigr]|>5$$
$$5>\bigl[|x|-1\bigr]>-5$$

I don't know whether I am doing right or wrong

Comment: In question x is within modulus function and |x|-1 is under greatest integer function

Comment: You are right, I was concentrating on the funny floor symbol.

Comment: You and me both, just making sure I wasn't misdirecting poor @rst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it all correct until the very end! You're right to restrict $|[|x|-1]| - 5 > 0$. However, at the end, you conclude that $5 > [|x|-1] > -5$, when in fact $|[|x|-1]| > 5$ implies that $[|x|-1] > 5$ or $[|x|-1] < -5$.

From here, we note that $[|x| - 1] = [|x|] - 1$, so we want to see where $[|x|] > 6$ and where $[|x|] < -4$. Since $|x| \geq 0$, the latter is clearly impossible. We thus see that we must have $[|x|] > 6$, which means that $x \geq 7$ or $x \leq -7$ (since we have $[|x|]$ is strictly greater than 6.)

Comment: OK,After that how solve the question futher. I have no idea for $[.]$

Comment: @rst, I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Is there no change for $[ |x|] >6$ i.e when we remove $[.]$ function ??

Comment: then I think ans should be $x>7 $or $x<-7$

Comment: What will happen if we have $[|x|] <6$ ??

Comment: @rst, if we have $[|x|] <6$, then we have that $[|x| - 1] < 5$, and since $[|x| - 1] \geq -1$ for all $x$, we have $|[|x|-1]| < 5$. In this case, we have $|[|x|-1]| - 5 < 0$, which is what we wanted to avoid.

Comment: I mean,what is the value of x if $(1)[x]<6$ , $(2)[x]<-6$, $(3)[x]>-6$

Comment: (1) If $[x] < 6$, then it follows that $x < 6$, as $[x] \leq 5$ for $x < 6$. (2) If $[x] < - 6$, then $x < -6$, as $[x] \leq -7$ for $x < - 6$. (3) If $[x] > -6$, then $x \geq -5$, as $x \leq -6$ for $x < -5$.

Comment: thanks,you really cleared my doubts

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help! :)